# Phoenician alphabet

Tags: languages, greek

Can I use the [phoenician alphabet](https://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ph%C3%B6nizisches_Alphabet) on latex? If yes How?

I didn't find it on the internet.

Comment: You can try this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/phoenician .

Comment: If XeTeX or LuaTeX is an option, you can have a look at https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/176.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{phoenician}

\begin{document}
try this text

\phncfamily% see manual p. 2 ff; may not be necessary
\textphnc{try this text}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]